# How to solve this differential equation with coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have $y' =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-2 & 2 & 0 \\
3 & 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix} \cdot y$

from this we know:
$y_1' = y_2$
$y_2' =-2y_1 + 2y_2$
$y_3' = 3y_1+y_2+3y_3$

I only know how to solve 
inhomogeneous/homogeneous differential equations, separation of variables, second order linear differential equation and variation of constants yet

Comment: Have you learned about eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes but not how to use them to solve differential equations

Comment: For example, see: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~xchen/teach/ode/ExpMatrix.pdf . There are also many examples on the site, for example; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213735/system-of-differential-equations-3x3?rq=1

Comment: This system can be solved by brute force, if you don't know the methods in the other comments.You can use the first equation to turn the second equation entirely into an equation in $y_1$. With that solution, you can then solve the second equation for $y_2$. This makes $y_3$ mildly painful, but solvable in principle.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very convenient question specially in system controls. In fact, such equations can be solved using Laplace transform. A Laplace transform imposed on a vector, performs solely on each entry and the result are then gathered as a Laplace vector. Considering these descriptions we have:
$$\LARGE y^{'}=Ay$$
taking Laplace transform we obtain:
$$\LARGE\mathscr L(y^{'}(t))=A\mathscr L(y(t))$$
which by defining $Y(s)=\mathscr L(y^{'}(t))$ yields to:
$$\LARGE sY(s)-y(0^-)=AY(s)$$
by substitution and factorizing we have:
$$\LARGE (sI-A)Y(s)=y(0^-)$$
or:
$$\LARGE Y(s)=(sI-A)^{-1}y(0^-)$$
and finally after taking inverse Laplace transform we can extract the answer:
$$\LARGE y(t)=\mathscr L^{-1}((sI-A)^{-1}y(0^-))$$
Here, $y(0^-)$ denotes vector of initial conditions and $y(t)'s$ are most generally defined as $Condition Variables$